# REST Call with list of headers

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, client

I have the following code snippet for invoking rest call. I have around 8 headers to pass on for this rest call. But the problem is that it is difficult to manage. If in case the list of headers are increased in future, I need to change `evaluateChange` method signature to include the additional headers as method `params`.

```
@Path("/v1/restclienturi/")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface RestClient {

    @POST
    @Path("/samplecall/evaluate")
    Response evaluateChange(
            @HeaderParam("HEADER1") String header1,
            @HeaderParam("HEADER2") String header2,
            @HeaderParam("HEADER3") String header3,
            @HeaderParam("HEADER4") String header4,
            @HeaderParam("HEADER5") String header5,
            @HeaderParam("HEADER6") String header6,
            @HeaderParam("HEADER7") String header7,
            @HeaderParam("HEADER8") String header8,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response, Request request);
}
```

Please provide your thoughts or code snippet to accommodate this.

I tried the following code snippet but it did not work(where headerMap contains all the 8 headers in it):

```
@Path("/v1/restclienturi/")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface RestClient {

    @POST
    @Path("/samplecall/evaluate")
    Response evaluateChange(
            @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response, Request request);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution using javax.ws.rs.core.Form:

```
 @Path("/v1/restclienturi/")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface RestClient {

    @POST
    @Path("/samplecall/evaluate")
    Response evaluateChange(
            @Form MyHeader headers,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response, Request request);
}
```

The following is the MyHeader which is a pojo:

```
public class MyHeader{
@HeaderParam("HEADER1")
    private String header1;

    @HeaderParam("HEADER2")
    private String header2;
.....
// getters and setters present
}
```

Instantiate MyHeader and set the values to pass it on to the REST service like:

```
MyHeader headers = new MyHeader();
headers.setHeader1("HEADER1_VALUE");
...
```

and call: `evaluateChange(headers, null,request);`

**PROBLEM:**
The very big problem with this approach is that everytime there is a new header added we need to make a code change to set and get the values. If the solution is something like passing as a colletion then we don't have that code change involved when new headers are added. like:

```
Map<String,String> headersMap = new HashMap();
headers.put("HEADER1","HEADER1_VALUE");
....
evaluateChange(headersMap,null,request);
```

I am looking for a solution like this. But the above code did not work. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: You already selected you own answer as the right answer, do you still need help or not? It seems in any case that you are trying to implement something like a factory. You could directly implement the factory pattern as defined in the theory.

Comment: @Rafa: I found the solution but it still has a problem as stated. Implementing factory or anyother design pattern doesnt solve the problem(as the REST service is not accepting the headers when used factory pattern).

Comment: @Arun I have a new solution to create multiple headers as you needed. please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35581805/5678086)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but if you want to get all headers how about this:

```java
public Response evaluateChange(@Context HttpHeaders headers, ...) {
    String header1 = headers.getRequestHeader("HEADER1").get(0);
    ...
}
```

Found some more code about this here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/

Edit: How to call the method with a map of key-values.

```java
public class MapHttpHeaders implements HttpHeaders {
   private Map<String, String> values;

   public MapHttpHeaders(Map<String, String> values) {
      this.values = values;
   }

   @Override
   public String getHeaderString(String key) {
      return values.get(key);
   }

   @Override
   public List<String> getRequestHeader(String key) {
      String value = getHeaderString(key);
      if (value == null) {
         return null;
      } else {
         return asList(value);
      }
   }
   ...and so on...
}
```

And then just do:

```java
evaluateChange(new MapHttpHeaders(values), ...);
```

Comment: Brautigam: From your solution, say I m trying to call this evaluateChange() api. I need to pass headers to this method. I have this headers as a hashmap in my codebase. How do you pass it to this method(as this method expects only HttpHeaders). Please provide a sample code.

Comment: You just have to implement the HttpHeaders interface to work from a Map, see above my edit. Most methods don't need to do anything, the most important ones are shown above.

Comment: I tried the above implementation, I am still not able to pass the headers. I tried overriding all the methods as well. Still no use. Any pointers or idea how this HttpHeaders will be read in the server side...

Comment: The serverside will pass you the parameter automatically. If your endpoint is deployed it should work. The implementation above is only for testing.

Comment: I also tried the following code snippet instead of @Context:
public Response evaluateChange(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap, ...) {
    String header1 = headers.getRequestHeader("HEADER1").get(0);
    ...
}

Still of no use.

Comment: Sorry the headers are not passed on.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details? What HTTP request did you try? What did your method receive? Null for the headers? If not, what headers did it actually contain?

Comment: I have kept a debug point at the method call[evaluateChange(new MapHttpHeaders(values), ...);]. I was able to analyse the headers being populated but after calling this method I am getting 400 bad request exception. This is thrown by the REST service when the mandatory headers are not passed. If I follow the implementation as show in the question (like passing every header as  @HeaderParam("HEADER1") String header1,...) then the request is passed on without any 400 bad request exception.

Comment: How do you make the request? What is your request exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just inject HttpServletRequest and then use its getHeader(String name) method?

API

```
@POST
@Path("/samplecall/evaluate")
Response evaluateChange(
        @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response, 
        @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        Request request);
```

Impl

```
@Override
public Response evaluateChange(
        @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response, 
        @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        Request request) {


    String header1 = httpRequest.getHeader("HEADER1");
    ...
```

Of course, that way you are hiding part of your contract in the implementation.

Comment: I am the client not the service... Need to form and pass this HttpServletRequest

Answer (score 1):

You can send all headers set in a MultivaluedHashMap (javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap) to the Form. this is an acceptable constructor argument for the Form.

```
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> headerMap = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
    headersMap.putSingle("HEADER1","HEADER1_VALUE");
    headersMap.putSingle("HEADER2","HEADER1_VALUE");
    .
    .
    .
    headersMap.putSingle("HEADER8","HEADER8_VALUE");

    evaluateChange(headersMap,null,request);
```

and change your `evaluateChange` as below,

```
Response evaluateChange(
        @Form MultivaluedMap headers,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response, Request request);
```

Hope this helps.. Good luck !!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying a `Map` and not simply a `List`:

```java
@Path("/v1/restclienturi/")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface RestClient {

    @POST
    @Path("/samplecall/evaluate")
    Response evaluateChange(
            @HeaderParam("HEADER") List<String> headers,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response, Request request
    );
}
```

Now I did not test this, but this would require all HeaderParams to be called 'HEADER', and they will/should be stored in the `List<String>` following the order of occurrence.